# ¿Cómo sería una expresión regular que acepte un sólo cero al inicio de la cadena?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs-2.0

Estoy validando un campo de `Temperatura`, el cual puede aceptar las siguientes cadenas:

> `-05`, `-2`, `-0`, `0`, `02`, `5`, `30`...

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular `/-?[0-9]+(\d+)/`, el cual no puedo validar que al inicio sólo pueda tener un cero.

Es validación con *Javascript*, algunas cadenas que no puede tener son:

> `00`, `003`, `-003`, `-00`...

La expresión regular necesito la necesito para validar un `input` de *HTML* usando `ng-pattern` de *Angular*.

Si existe otra herramienta que me recomienden es bienvenida.

Comment: No entendí muy bien lo que buscas, ¿las cadenas que muestras son valores validos?, esta expresión acepta un 0 al inicio y un segundo dígito entre 1 y 9 : ^[0][1-9]{1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deconstruyendo lo que se intenta tomar como válido, sería:

- un signo negativo, opcional.
- dos opciones:

  - un cero opcional, seguido de un dígito que no es cero (1 a 9), y luego cualquier cantidad de dígitos más.
  - un cero solamente, y se termina el string ahí.

### Expresión regular:

```
/^-?(?:0?[1-9]\d*|0)$/
```

- `^` - coincide con el [inicio del string](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-caret).
- `-?` - Un signo negativo opcional (el `?` lo [repite 0 o 1 vez](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark)).
- `(?:0?[1-9]\d*|0)` - [grupo sin captura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Usando_par%C3%A9ntesis) que coincide con 2 [alternativas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or):

  1. `0?[1-9]\d*` un cero opcional, un dígito entre 1 y 9, y más dígitos (0 a 9) [repetidos entre 0 e infinitas veces](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-asterisk).
  2. `0` - un cero literal.
- `$` - coincide con el [fin del string](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-dollar).

---

Ejemplo utilizándolo con ng-pattern:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="">

  <p>Enteros con máximo un cero a la izquierda:</p>

  <form name="formulario">
    <input name="entero" ng-model="entero" required ng-pattern="/^-?(?:0?[1-9]\d*|0)$/">
  </form>

  <p>¿El número es válido?</p>
  <h1>{{formulario.entero.$valid}}</h1>

</body>
```

Comment: +1 (lamentablemente, en este sitio lograr que la pregunta esté bien formulada es 90% del problema). Tal vez sería bueno que expliques cómo está armada la expresión regular.

Comment: @leonbloy actualizado.